# How to delete more than one relationship in neo4j using cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to remove more than one relationship but not all relationship for specific node,

I can delete single relationship or every relationship but not more than one specific relationship

```
match(n:Student{id:2),
(n)-[r1:STUDENT_CLASS]->(b:Class),
(n)-[r2:STUDENT_RANK]->(m:Rank)
delete r1,r2
return n.name
```

I connected **Student** node with 3 common nodes(**School,Class,Rank**) with different relationship.
I want to delete 2 relationship(**Class,Rank**) for particular student in same query without affecting another node's(**School**) relationship with **Student** node.

Comment: By more than one specific relationship, what exactly do you mean? A relationship of a specific type? Or more than one relationship with a specific node?

Comment: please give us an example with sample data on what to delete and NOT to delete. thanks.

Comment: I gave an example for my question. It would be great if you give solution for this issue. Thank you in advance. @jose_bacoy

Comment: Your query looks good. What is the issue or problem that you get?

Comment: I could not delete two relationship at same time as I used in this query @jose_bacoy

Comment: I updated my question. Kindly review it @CharchitKapoor

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical stroke | acts as an OR operator when selecting relationships:

```
match (n:Student {id:2})-[r:STUDENT_CLASS|STUDENT_RANK]->(b)
where b:Class or b:Rank
delete r
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is logically correct but syntactically wrong:

```
match(n:Student{id:2), <--- missed a closing curly brace here
(n)-[r1:STUDENT_CLASS]->(b:Class),
(n)-[r2:STUDENT_RANK]->(m:Rank)
delete r1,r2
return n.name
```

Try this:

```
match(n:Student{id:2}),
(n)-[r1:STUDENT_CLASS]->(b:Class),
(n)-[r2:STUDENT_RANK]->(m:Rank)
delete r1,r2
return n.name
```

Comment: Thank you I updated it. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to update.